# Changing stacking order for CSS pseudo element

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am in the process of designing a 3 stage progress bar in pure CSS.  My current effort is shown below.

```css
#progBar
{
 background-color:#bdbdbd;
 padding:1.5vw;  
 position:relative; 
 height:9vw;
}
.progcapt
{
 background-color: #526cfd;
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #526cfd; 
 -webkit-background-clip:text;
 font-family:'arial black';
 font-size:3vw
}
#cOne
{
 position:absolute;
 left:calc(50% - 2.5vw);
 top:calc(50% - 2.5vw);
 border-radius:5vw;
 height:5vw;
 width:5vw;
 border:1px solid #526cfd;
 text-align:center;
 display:flex;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 box-shadow:0px 0px 3vw #526cfd;
 background-color:white;

}
#cOne::before
{
 position:absolute;
 width:50vw;
 height:1vw;   
 background-color:rgba(82,108,253,0.5);
 content:'';
/*z-index:-1; does not give the expected result*/
}
#cOneRing
{
 position:absolute; 
 top:-calc(0.5vw + 1px);
 left:-calc(0.5vw + 1px);
 width:6vw;
 height:6vw;
 border:1px solid #526cfd;
 border-radius:6vw;
 
}
```

```html
 <div id='progBar'>
    <div id='cOne'>
     <span class='progcapt'>1</span>
     <div id='cOneRing'>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The intent here is this

- There will be three disc, one for each step
- I am using the central disc as my "anchor"
- Each disc is shown with an annular border which I create by absolutely positioning the disc and making the annulus its child.
- The `::before` pseudo-element for this anchor is used to create the track for the progress bar
- The ensemble - the three circles and the track - are placed in an relatively positioned rectangular bar which acts as the background

The issue I have run into - I thought I would be able to send the track bar **behind** its parent disc element by setting its z-index attribute to -1.  However, that simply causes it to disappear altogether.  Clearly, I am doing something wrong here but I am unable to spot what that might be.  Hopefully, someone here will be able to spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you need this

```
#progBar {z-index: -2;}
#cOne::after { z-index: -1;}
```

```css
    #progBar
    {
    z-index: -2;
     background-color:#bdbdbd;
     padding:1.5vw;  
     position:relative; 
     height:9vw;
    }
    .progcapt
    {
     background-color: #526cfd;
     color: transparent;
     text-shadow: 0px 2px 3px #526cfd; 
     -webkit-background-clip:text;
     font-family:'arial black';
     font-size:3vw
    }
    #cOne
    {
     position:absolute;
     left:calc(50% - 2.5vw);
     top:calc(50% - 2.5vw);
     border-radius:5vw;
     height:5vw;
     width:5vw;
     border:1px solid #526cfd;
     text-align:center;
     display:flex;
     align-items:center;
     justify-content:center;
     box-shadow:0px 0px 3vw #526cfd;
     background-color:white;

    }
    #cOne::before
    {
     position:absolute;
     width:50vw;
     height:1vw;   
     background-color:rgba(82,108,253,0.5);
     content:'';
     z-index:-1; 
    }
    #cOneRing
    {
     position:absolute; 
     top:-calc(0.5vw + 1px);
     left:-calc(0.5vw + 1px);
     width:6vw;
     height:6vw;
     border:1px solid #526cfd;
     border-radius:6vw;
     
    }
```

```html
     <div id='progBar'>
        <div id='cOne'>
         <span class='progcapt'>1</span>
         <div id='cOneRing'>&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
      </div>
```